# How To Determine If Outlook Is Fully Launched from my C# Add-In?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

Windows users can right-click on any file in explorer and go to *Send to > Mail recipient*

This launches a new message in a compose inspector with the file attached and some pre-populated text. However, it does not seem to fully launch the Outlook application.

This causes problems when my Add-In tries to close the inspector and run some cleanup code (which it does successfully when Outlook is fully launched). The Add-In suspends and crashes Outlook when trying to run the clean up code because closing the inspector is trying to close Outlook.

**Is there a way using C# to determine whether Outlook is fully launched or just in this compose-only mode?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the problematic snippet of your code?

You can check if there are any open explorers by checking the Application.Explorers.Count property.

Comment: the problem is that I call `inspector.Close();` then there is more code that typically runs, but in this compose-only mode when closing the inspector, it is closing Outlook, then locking up because it is also trying to continue running my code while exiting.

I had not thought about checking the Explorer count. I will try that out.

Comment: Although this did not solve my problem, it is a solution to the question I asked. I will keep digging into my issue to find the right question.